# Query to display rows having duplicate values in 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Table1:

```
id|name|city
-------------
1 | bat|nyc
2 | cat|del
2 | rat|bom
3 | mat|xyz
```

Table2

```
id|name|city
--------------
1 |bat|dsada
2 |cat|sadasd
3 |rat|sdasdas
2 |rat|asdas
```

I need a query to display rows where BOTH id and name are same among two tables in above example the query must return 
i need a query to display the rows

```
1|bat|nyc
2|cat|del
```

from first table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to join both the table like as below

```
select tabl1.* from table1
inner join table2
on table1.id=table2.id and table1.name=table2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and probably most effcient) would be to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id,name,city FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2
   WHERE t2.name = t1.name
   AND t2.id  = t1.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   T1.id, T1.name
from Table1 as T1
where
    exists (select * from Table2 as T2 where T2.id = T1.id and T2.name = T1.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: the JOIN will make sure both condition are fulfilled, i.e. both records from the two tables have the same value for `id` and `name`

```
Select t1.name, t1.city from Table1 t1
 Join Table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id and 
        t1.name = t2.name
```

Comment: 'select *'  and 'on' instead 'where'

Comment: @codingbiz - you need to write t1.name, t1.city  because otherwise it will give you ambiguous column error

Comment: Good spot. Wasn't tested in query window?